# pdo wrapper last id return 0

Tags: php, pdo

hello Iam trying to make a project using php mvc and I used on it pdo wrapper package
the main problem that when I use lastinsertid it always return 0 I know that I should use the same connection but in my case with the package how can I do it??

this is the model code

```
<?php
   namespace MVC\core;
    use Dcblogdev\PdoWrapper\Database as Database;

    class model{
   static function db(){
    $options = [
    //required
    'username' => 'root',
    'database' => 'gallery',
    //optional
    'password' => '',
    'type' => 'mysql',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '3306'
     ];
      return  $db = new Database($options);
    }
    }
    ?>
```

and here where I use the pdo with my function

```
    <?php
namespace MVC\model;
use MVC\core\model;
use MVC\core\session;
class adminpost extends model {
function getCategory(){
    return  model::db()->rows("SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE id NOT in (SELECT parent_id from category)");
}
function getposts(){
    return  model::db()->rows("select * from posts");
}
function getpostsByCategory($id){
    return  model::db()->rows("select * from posts where category_id = ?",[$id]);
}
function insertimage($data){
    return model::db()->insert('images', $data);

}
function insertpost($data){
     return model::db()->insert('posts', $data);

}
function lastid(){
    return model::db()->lastInsertId();

}
}


?>
```

and here is the controller where I use the model function

```
class adminpostcontroller extends controller{
function postinsert(){
$post = new adminpost;
$data = [
'title'=>$_POST['title'],
'text'=>$_POST['text']
];
$insert = $post->insertpost($data);
}
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming its that every time you call `model::db()` you're establishing a new connection due to `new Database($options)`, you need to create and retain one connection for the duration of your actions via a static reference.

edit: Converted to answer

Comment: how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming its that every time you call `model::db()` you're establishing a new connection due to `new Database($options)`, you need to create and retain one connection for the duration of your actions via a static reference or another most appropriate means.

A "cheap" way to do this is

```
static $db;
return isset( $db ) ? $db : $db = new Database($options);
```

Other ways could be to create a reference in your class like `static $db;` and use `static::$db`

```
class model{
  static $db;
```

followed by

```
return isset( static::$db ) ? static::$db : static::$db = new Database($options);
```

Comment: where i should put this code?

Comment: Where you create your new instance of your `Database` object

Comment: If there's ever a need to have multiple connections with different connection options you may need to consider what happens then, but lets assume you only need the one active connection and you'll be fine :)